# permission denied on include file php

Tags: php, apache, permissions

Here is my

**Code:**

```
include     'c:/wamp/www/google-api/src/';
require_once  'c:/wamp/www/google-api/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'c:wamp/www/google-api/src/Google/Service.php';
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\google-api\src): failed to open stream: Permission denied in      C:\wamp\www\HelloAnalyticsApi.php on line 1
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: You are include a folder? Is that right?

Comment: You can't include folders

Comment: Shouldn't be include but a function setting include path

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem with "Permission denied" errors (or other permissions problems) when including files, check:

1) That the file you are trying to include has the appropriate "r" (read) permission set, and
2) That all the directories that are ancestors of the included file, but not of the script including the file, have the appropriate "x" (execute/search) permission set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include a whole folder using `include` directly. To do you have to use a loop with the [glob](http://php.net/glob) function

```
foreach (glob("c:/wamp/www/google-api/src/*.php") as $file)
{
    include $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try insert the name of file after src.

By **php.net**  :)
The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Comment: what to do if i have to include a folder

Comment: You don't include folders only files in folders. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain what you need make exactly please? I have used the google api and have never needed to add an entire folder.